# Update and store a global Julia array with !push

Tags: arrays, julia, push, global, read-eval-print-loop

I'm a bit puzzled about the way that Julia 1.0.3 treats global variables.  Is there a way to use !push to update a global array?

While playing in the REPL, I want to update a global variable, then `push!` the result to a global array to store it.

```
var = [1]
res = []

for i in 1:5
  global var
  global res
  push!(var,i)
  print(string(var,"\n"))
  push!(res,var)
end
```

However, the values stored in `res` are as follows:

```
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Whereas I would expect this:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Particularly puzzling since behaviour seems as expected with variables, instead of arrays:

```
var = 1
res = []

for i in 1:5
  global var
  global res
  var = var + i
  print(string(var,"\n"))
  push!(res, var)
end
```

Which gives expected result:

```
  2
  4
  7
 11
 16
```

I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing *the same `var` array* to every spot in the `res` array.  For example:

```
julia> var = [1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> res = [var, var]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]
 [1]

julia> var[1] = 2
2

julia> res
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2]
 [2]
```

Both elements in the `res` array *are* `var` itself. So if you modify `var` (with `push!` or indexed assignment or somesuch), then no matter how you access it you'll see those modifications.

This doesn't occur with numbers because you cannot modify numbers themselves.  You can change *which* number is stored in an array, but you cannot change the number `1` to represent `2` everywhere that `1` had previously been used — that's the equivalent of what's happening here.

To fix this, you'll often want to just create your `var` array inside the for loop (instead of outside it).  But in this case, since you're iteratively adding things to `var` and want to save that intermediate state, you can use `copy`:

```
julia> for i in 1:5
         global var
         global res
         push!(var,i)
         print(string(var,"\n"))
         push!(res,copy(var))
       end
Any[1]
Any[1, 2]
Any[1, 2, 3]
Any[1, 2, 3, 4]
Any[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

julia> res
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[1]
 Any[1, 2]
 Any[1, 2, 3]
 Any[1, 2, 3, 4]
 Any[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```